# How to sum a row based on changing months that I want to specify?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I have an excel/sheets file, I am trying to automate calculations based on the month I've selected.

My table looks like this, however for posterity imagine it has twelve full months. I am trying to calculate the total salary based on the month I've chosen, what I've called "Specific Summed Salary" in the table below. For example, if I chose January it would return a sum of 250. If I've selected March it would be 650 (250+150+250). Specific Summed Salary is a value that changes based on the month I've selected.

Here is my core table below. Total Salary would be the sum after 12 months, which is easy enough to determine as its known time value(12 months). In practice, Salary values would be be 0 in months that havent yet occurred. Where I am struggling is the Specific Summed Salary where the summation of months is based on the month selected.

| Month | January | February | March | April | Specific Summed Salary | Total Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Salary 1 | 100 | 50 | 150 | 200 | ??? | Annual Total |
| Salary 2 | 150 | 100 | 100 | 150 | ??? | Annual Total |
| Total | 250 | 150 | 250 | 350 | ??? | Annual Total |

In the same sheet I have small table that is the "Current Month Selector". In this table, the current month selection was done by creating a drop down list. In this example I've chosen April. The numerical value of the month was determined using this formula: =month(1&left(U3,3)).

| Current Month | April |
| --- | --- |
| Current Month (numerical) | 4 |

What I'd like to do now is that, I choose a specific month in the current month selector drop down, and the Specific Summed Salary is then calculated appropriately.

I tried using something like this, however it only returned the value of the specific month. =SUMIFS(B9:M9,$B$1:$M$1,$U$3) where B9:M9 was the salary row. B1:M1 was the month row, and U3 was the name of the month from dropdown list of the Month Selector. I get what its doing, its returning the value of matching month, not summing the values from the start of the year to that month. But im not sure how and I cant get it to dynamically sum up values based on month.

Comment: `=SUMIFS(B2:M2,B$1:M$1,"<="&DATE(2023,$U$3,1))` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: A Sum function that depending on the selected month will sum all salaries up to that month, what I did is this:

```
=SUM(E5:XLOOKUP($B$12,$E$4:$P$4,$E$4:$P$4))
```

Where E5 is the very first salary for that year and that (make sure to change it per salary row)
B12 is the month you've selected
E4:P4 is your month row

What this formula does is sum all monthly salaries up to the selected month.

[image: My recreation of the data here]

Note that I also did a xlookup for the monthly numeric values in case you need to use them later the formula is:

```
=XLOOKUP(B12,A16:A27,B16:B27)
```

Where B12 is the month (selected by drop down list)
A16:A27 are the months
B16:B27 are the numeric values

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(B2:E2*(MONTH(1&$B$1:$E$1)<=MONTH(1&$D$7)))
```

[image]